# Vb.net sending form to another computer

Tags: vb.net, forms, image, send

I have a not typical question.

I have an application with charts which refreshes every minute (production data).
I just would like to see the form on different computer as a picture (with refreshing).
How to send it? Is it posible?
Everything what i can do at the moment is to send an email with screenshot attached.

Comment: There is nothing built-in to any of the desktop UI frameworks to do this, that I'm aware of.  So, short of something like VNC or remote desktop, you'll need to create a custom solution.  You could grab an image and send it, but that's hokey.  The typical solution would be to have the application post the data to a webservice, of some sort, and then other applications could query that webservice, from any machine, to get and display the data.  Alternatively, you could make a web site that can display the data that was posted to the webservice via any browser.

Comment: Ok, thaks for the ideas. Both of them are interesting. Second one seems to be more attractive, but i don't know anything about web applications. Is there any easy method to transfer winform application to web application? I have to say that app which i created just displays data, i don't need interaction at all.

Comment: If there was a way to automatically convert a desktop application into a web application, I wouldn't trust it.  There are many ways of writing web application using any number of different languages and technologies.  If you want to stick with VB.NET and Microsoft frameworks, the two popular options are WebForms and MVC, both via ASP.NET.  WebForms is more akin to desktop programming, but is older and more bloated.  MVC is the slicker more modern framework, but it's also likely more different from what you're used to.

Comment: I guess you aren't aware of likely search terms for what you want: if you search for "vb.net chat send picture" you'll get links to things like [Picture Chat for .NET](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/8165/Picture-Chat-for-NET).

Answer (score 0):

Like said in one of the comments I am not aware of anything that does this simply. What I would probably do as a quick slightly better solution than the email would be to upload the screen shot to some sort of photo hosting service such as Google Photos. Many of these services allow for photos to be uploaded and deleted via the API so you could just upload the new image and delete the old one after. Here is a link for Google Photos API documentation on uploading images: https://developers.google.com/photos/library/guides/upload-media

Answer (score -1):

So, what I did: My application saves data on the local disk. My IT department made a script which copies that data to server in 5 minutes interval and that data is loaded by the client.
I have no idea how to save data to server directly if the application runs on the computer which is outside the domain.
Everything works but i don't like this solution.

Thanks for answers.